# Yii dataprovider values

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to see what values are available inside dataprovider object which has been called by CActiveDataProvider in Yii. I tried print_r but it doesn't seem to tell me much.

Is there a debugging function which I could use?

Comment: Yes, you can use [var_dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: sorry but I've tried that and print_r but they do not give actual values

Comment: What do you mean by "actual values"?
print_r just outputs content with cast to string (e.g., false will be => "", so nothing on the screen).
var_dump outputs current type and value of content (e.g., false will be => (boolean) "false").

Answer (score 4):

I presume you don't want to inspect the data provider instance itself but it's data.

`CVarDumper::dump()` is an enhanced variant of PHP's `var_dump()` or `print_r()` where `CVarDumper::dumpAsString()` acts the same with the difference that the dump information will not be printed but returned as a string.

```
Yii::log(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($dataProvider->data));
// or
CVarDumper::dump($dataProvider->data);
```

See Yii's [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) documentation for what you can additionally inspect.

Answer (score 0):

`CVarDumper::dump()` is a slightly more powerful `var_dump` that usually gets things to the screen.  Or use a `Yii::log(...)` to log the information and see it in your various logging outputs.